# Cannot understand usage of "buyer" vs "seller" in particular article

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, logic

Probably my question is more about "logic" than about "language" but still it manifests some problems with my command of English.
So here is an excerpt of one article I am reading:

> In a way, the editors were all right. Mr Akerlof’s idea, eventually
>   published in the Quarterly Journal of Economics in 1970, was at once
>   simple and revolutionary. Suppose buyers in the used-car market value
>   good cars—“peaches”—at $1,000, and sellers at slightly less. A
>   malfunctioning used car—a “lemon”—is worth only $500 to buyers (and,
>   again, slightly less to sellers). If buyers can tell lemons and
>   peaches apart, trade in both will flourish. In reality, buyers might
>   struggle to tell the difference: scratches can be touched up, engine
>   problems left undisclosed, even odometers tampered with.

I do not understand why would a seller value a car slightly less than a buyer would value it. As far as I understand sellers always want to sell something the highest price possible.
Could you help me to get it clear?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about logic, human motivations, and economics, not "learning English".

Comment: I agree with you, and noted this in the first sentence of my question as well as in the tag.
I would also appreciate if you tell me more relevant target to post such questions.

Comment: There are the SO sites [Economics](http://economics.stackexchange.com/) and [Philosophy](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic), but either or both might think your question is a bit basic, even if in principle it might otherwise be On Topic. Obviously sellers (usually) want to sell at the highest price possible, but that's got little to do with how much they "value" it (i.e. - the maximum a *seller* would consider paying to buy the item, if he didn't currently have one).

Comment: thanks. SO site for Economics would suite me well. I somehow did not think about it.

Comment: I agree this is probably better suited to Economics, although they might reject it as being more about English Learning than market forces.  Which, by the way, is idiomatically called a [Catch-22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22_(logic)), from the Joseph Heller novel of the same name -- a situation that cannot be resolved due to conflicting bureaucratic rules.

Comment: There is perhaps an element of "language use" here, in that you need to be clear about exactly what we mean when we say *a seller **values** some item X at £Y*. In practice, the seller doesn't *personally* value many of the things he sells at all (perhaps he doesn't use X, or has his own X of better quality anyway, so having more X's just takes up space that he could use for things he *does* value). So pragmatically, we assume he would *only* be "valuing" additional X's at £Y because he thinks/knows he can ***sell*** them for ***at least that price***.

Comment: Following the above, but with stronger conviction. The logic problem seems to rest on a definitional issue, reasonably considered on topic, I think, because of the multiple connotations of *value* and the relative complexity of the text. I've submitted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A seller has to buy or make what he/she sells to others.

If the seller buys his products, he will want to buy them at a lower price than what he sells them to others, the difference being his profit.

So I am understanding this:

> Suppose buyers in the used-car market value good cars—“peaches”—at $1,000, and sellers at slightly less.

to mean that if a *re*seller and a buyer are looking at the same car, they of course are going to think of it as worth different amounts, insofar as their cost.

The term "reseller" may have been more accurate, or "retail seller".  Also the use of the term *value* to mean strictly "what I am willing to pay for X" rather than more generally "what amount of money would someone be willing to pay for X" is confusing, but it's valid.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem lies in understanding the meaning of *value* here.

This is betrayed in the OP's statements placed below the excerpt.

*To value,* in this context, refers to estimating worth, not placing a price on or making an offer.

We can simplify an essential element of the meaning like this:

> If a buyer thinks a car is worth $1,000, and a seller thinks the car is worth somewhat less, then a trade is likely to happen.

This is because the seller would be getting somewhat more than she thinks it is worth (making a profit). And the buyer is paying what he thinks it is worth (getting a fair deal).

*value*
verb
1.
estimate the monetary worth of.

--Google.com define operation (define value)